# pentaho create archive folder with MM-YYYY

Tags: zip, pentaho, archive, kettle

I would like to archive every file in a folder by putting it in another archive folder with a name like this: "Archive/myfolder-06-2014"

My problem is how to retrieve the current month and year and then how to create a folder (if it does not already exist) with these data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution may be a little awkward (due to the required fuss) but it seems to work. The idea is to precompute the target filename in a seperate transformation and store it as a system variable (`TARGET_ZIP_FILENAME`):

[image: Transformation for retrievign the target zip filename]

The following diagrams show the settings of selected components.

- Get the current time...

[image: Get current time]

- Provide the pattern of the target filename as a string constant...

[image: Provide target filename pattern]

- Extract the month and year as formatted integers...

[image: Extract month and year from current time]

- Replace the month in the pattern (the year will work equivalently)

[image: Replace month in pattern]

- Set the resulting filename as a system variable

[image: Set variable containing target filename]

The main job will call the transformation and use the system variable as the zip target filename.

[image: Main job]

Also you have to make sure that the setting `Create Parent folder` is active:
[image: Settings of the 'zip file' component]

Comment: Very good answer, but a simplification to your process would be on the calculator step using a "Create a copy of field A", using your timestamp as field A, choose string as the data type and setting the format to be "yyyy_MM".